# Jquery - Remove Select Items (loop through array)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code I am using to remove select items based on the var "ColTypeCus".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ColTypeCus = '$FooVar';


    if (ColTypeCus.substr(0, 21) == "Machinery") {
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='3']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='1']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='2']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='4']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='5']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='12']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='13']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='14']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='15']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='16']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='18']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='19']").remove();
    }

    else if (ColTypeCus.substr(0, 7) == "Banking") {
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='17']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='3']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='7']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='8']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='9']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='10']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='11']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='12']").remove();
    }

    else if (ColTypeCus.substr(0, 19) == "Inventory") {
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='3']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='1']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='2']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='4']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='5']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='12']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='14']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='15']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='16']").remove();
        $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='18']").remove();
    }

});
```

It works great, but I wanted to know if there was a more elegant way (fewer lines of code) I could implement to do the same thing.

One idea was to specify which items to remove listed in array and loop through the items.

```
***pseudocode***
    var ColType = ''
    var RemoveThis = ''

    if Coltype = "Machinery"
       RemoveThis = ('1,3,5,7,9');
             {
               $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='+RemoveThis+']").remove();
              }

    elseif Coltype = "Banking"
       RemoveThis = ('2,4,6,8');
            {
                $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='+RemoveThis+']").remove();
            }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question should be moved to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), methinks.

Comment: mine worked perfectly too
http://jsfiddle.net/egRv2/1/

Comment: sorry - didnt see your jsfiddle solution in your original post. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a for loop:

```
var items_to_remove = [1,3,5,7,9]

for(var i in items_to_remove) {
    $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value=" + items_to_remove[i] + "]").remove();
}
```

Comment: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nkrid/egRv2/)

Answer (score 4):

You can make a function to simplify it by passing the select object and array of values for which you want to remove options.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/tJL2S/)**

```
function removeFromSelect(yourSelect, arrOptionsVal)
{
    $(yourSelect).find('option').filter(function(){
         return arrOptionsVal.indexOf(this.value) != -1;
    }).remove();      
}
```

This is how you call it

```
removeFromSelect($('#sel1'), ['3','4']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could at least simplify your code by writing a helper function:

```
function removeItem(id) {
    $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='"+id+"']").remove();
}
...
removeItem(3);
removeItem(5);
etc;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$.each([1,3,5,7,9], function() {
    $("select#ctl00_PageBody_lstValuationSource option[value='"+this+"']").remove();
});
```